# Displaying map in p.mapper framework for UMN MapServer?

Tags: mapserver, p-mapper

I want to display map in p.mapper. I've done some goggling and looked at some examples but can't seem to make what I've seen work. Can someone recommend a link or example I can look at?

I'm using mapserver and p.mapper

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  I notice that you have tags for [tag:qgis], [tag:postgresql] and [tag:arcview] but make no mention of using any of them in the body of your question.  Tags are used by people specializing in particular products and topics to find questions that they can apply those skills to so I would recommend using the edit button to remove any tags that do not apply to the body of your question.

Comment: You seem to have already posted this on Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/q/26228201/398670). Please don't copy your questions between sites, especially without even linking between them. It wastes the time of people answering questions. Please pick one and delete the other.

Comment: late comment, but did you try the p.mapper mailing list? it's still active https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/pmapper-users

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you those steps:

- Load your data inside QGIS and do a basic style for all the layers;
- Use the RT MapServer Exporter plugin to convert your project in a mapfile;
- Install Pmapper and use the mapfile for you webgis application

As side note, you can use the shp2img command to check the mapfile syntax.